# SwiftUI NavigationLink isActive Binding Not Updated/Working

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I have the following:

```
@State private var showNext = false

...
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: NextView(showSelf: $showNext),
                           isActive: $showNext) { EmptyView() }

            Button("Show Next") {
                showNext = true
            }
        }
    }

...

struct NextView: View {
    @Binding var showSelf: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("Next")
         .navigationTitle("Next")

        Button("Dismiss") {
            showSelf = false
        }
            .padding(30)
    }
}
```

When tapping `Show Next`, the `NextView` is shown as expected.

But when tapping `Dismiss`, nothing happens.

Turns out that `showSelf` was already `false` before it's set to `false`.  So it seems something went wrong with passing the binding into `NextView`.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was caused by `NavigationStack`.  When I replaced it with `NavigationView` it worked as expected.

The `isActive` binding of `NavigationLink` does not appear to work (or to be supported) when embedded in a `NavigationStack`.

Answer (score 1):

`isActive` binding is for `NavigationView`, try:

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)`
```

Comment: Why does the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview) not talk about a required main and detail view?  How does use of `EmptyView` cause my binding to have the wrong value?  What do you mean with "navigation to break"; I didn't talk about that?

Comment: I meant isActive breaking

Comment: Thanks for you time!  Your `NextView` doesn't fix this issue.  Where did you read that `NavuigationView` requires a main and detail view?

Comment: Text(“Select a note”) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73873498/1971013

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix code for iOS >= 16 (*NavigationStack*) and for iOS < 16 (the previous way to handle *NavigationLink*). Similarly for the dismiss part, which is iOS < 15.

Here is your code for iOS 16:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    NextView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Show next view")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You are in the next view")
            Button("Dismiss", action: dismiss.callAsFunction)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Next")
    }
}
```

I have used the simplest construction of *NavigationLink*. A more complex one would be used in conjunction with *.navigationDestination*. The best examples I have found are here:

- https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/15/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-navigator-pattern/
- https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/21/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-deep-linking/
- https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/78-reverse-engineering-swiftui-s-navigationpath-codability

And if you want to dive more into very strange behaviour of the stack, you can look at my post here: [Found a strange behaviour of @State when combined to the new Navigation Stack - Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885353/found-a-strange-behaviour-of-state-when-combined-to-the-new-navigation-stack)

If you need to produce code for iOS < 16, you should replace *NavigationStack* with *NavigationView* and work from there.