# Found a strange behaviour of @State when combined to the new Navigation Stack - Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-state, swiftui-navigationstack

I have transitioned my swiftui app to the new **NavigationStack** programmatically managed using *NavigationStack(path: $visibilityStack)*. While doing so, I found an unexpected behaviour of @State that makes me think the view is not dismissed correctly.

In fact, when I am replacing the view with another one in the stack, the @State variable is keeping its current value instead of being initialised, as it should be when presenting a new view.

Is it a bug? Is it a misconception (mine or someone else :-))? Your thoughts are welcome. As it is, the only workaround I see is to maintain a state in another object and synchronise...

I have created a mini-project. To reproduce, click on the **NavigationLink**, then click on the 'show other fruits' button to change the **@State** in the current View, then click a fruit button to change the view. The new view appears with the previous state (*showMoreText* is true, although it is declared as false during init). While doing more tests, it also appears that *.onAppear* is not called either. When using the old style NavigationView and isPresented, views were correctly initialised.

Full code here (except App which is the basic one), which should have been a good tutorial.

EDIT per Yrb answer:
The data is handled in the fruitList of Model Fruit to keep our ViewController clean.

The controller FruitViewController is responsible to call the new views:

```
class Fruit: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // to conform to Identifiable
    var id: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.id = name
    }
    
    // to conform to Hashable which inherit from Equatable
    static func == (lhs: Fruit, rhs: Fruit) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.id == rhs.id)
    }
    
    // to conform to Hashable
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
let fruitList = [Fruit(name: "Banana"), Fruit(name: "Strawberry"), Fruit(name: "Pineapple")]

class FruitViewController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var visibilityStack : [Fruit] = []

    // the functions that programatically call a 'new' view
    func openView(fruit: Fruit) {
        visibilityStack.removeAll()
        visibilityStack.append(fruit)
//        visibilityStack[0] = fruit    // has the same effect
    }
    
    // another one giving an example of what could be a deep link
    func bananaAndStrawberry() {
        visibilityStack.append(fruitList[0])
        visibilityStack.append(fruitList[1])
    }
}
```

The main ContentView which provides the NavigatoinStack:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var fruitViewController = FruitViewController()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $fruitViewController.visibilityStack) {
            VStack {
                Button("Pile Banana and Strawberry", action: bananaAndStrawberry)
                    .padding(40)
                List(fruitList) {
                    fruit in NavigationLink(value: fruit) {
                        Text(fruit.id)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) {
                    fruit in FruitView(fruitViewController: fruitViewController, fruit: fruit)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func bananaAndStrawberry() {
        fruitViewController.bananaAndStrawberry()
    }
}
```

The subview FruitView where the @State variable should be initialised:

```
struct FruitView: View {
    // the state that will change and not be initialised
    @State private var showMoreText = false
    @ObservedObject var fruitViewController: FruitViewController
    var fruit: Fruit
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Selected fruit: " + fruit.id)
        if (showMoreText) {
            Text("The text should disappear when moving to another fruit")
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(fruitList) {
                    aFruit in Button(aFruit.id) {
                        fruitViewController.openView(fruit: aFruit)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Button("Show other fruits", action: showButtons)
        }
    }
    
    // let's change the state
    func showButtons() {
        showMoreText = true
    }
}
```

ADDENDUM after Yrb answer:

I have done another exercise, to maybe better explain my point. Add 3 views to the stack array with *visibilityStack.append* . Let's call the initial state: state 0. It will create a stack like this:

```
_View 1 - state 0_
_View 2 - state 0_
_View 3 - State 0_ (the one shown on the screen)
```

Let's now modify the state of our View 3 to obtain:

```
_View 1 - state 0_
_View 2 - state 0_ 
_View 3 - State 1_ (the one shown on the screen)
```

Can you tell me what is happening when you remove View 2 using *visibilityStack.remove(at: 1)*?

The answer is: you will obtain the following stack:

```
_View 1 - state 0_
_View 3 - State 0_ (the one shown on the screen)
```

So the *View 2* is not destroyed. The last View in the stack is the one that is destroyed.

To Yrb point, it seems like if NavigationStack was a mixed approach between the ability to deal with the views, but with a kind of Model in mind.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a reason Fruit is a class (reference type) rather than a Struct (value type). FWIW, I don't think that matters here. I changed it to a struct when playing around and I still got the same result.

Comment: No particular reason. I was just copying the Apple code, so we should ask Apple ;-)

Comment: just in case you don't see the edit adding a `.id(some Hashable)` to the view declaration does turn out to be much cleaner.  I like this solution much better than the `.onReicive` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to add: smallest amount of code that will force the navigation stack to see views of the same type as brand new instead of caching them is to add `.id(some Hashable)` to the view declaration.

In this case Fruit is hashable so we can just add `.id(fruit)`

```
    NavigationStack(path: $fruitViewController.visibilityStack) {
        ...
        .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) { fruit in FruitView(fruitViewController: fruitViewController, fruit: fruit).id(fruit)
        }
    }
```

---

I would say that Adkarma has a point. The view is not "deiniting" as one might expect because they've haven't simply loaded a new fruit. They've edited the actual navigation path.

The thing is the view's identity is being preserved because (simplification/educated guess warning) it is  `NavigationStack[0] as? FruitView` and `NavigationStack[0] as FruitView` is still there. The `NavigationStack` will not fully clean it up until the RootView has reappeared. `NavigationStack` doesn't clean up any views until the new one has appeared.

So, if you change `FruitViewController`  to:

```
    func openView(fruit: Fruit) {
        visibilityStack.append(fruit)
    }
```

The NavigationStack will work as expected and you will continue to add views to the stack - I've added a `counter` and the `visibilityStack` to the FruitView to make what's happening clearer as well as some messages to make it clearer when things get made and cleaned up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var fruitController = FruitViewController()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $fruitController.visibilityStack) {
            VStack {
                ...
            }
            .onAppear() {
                print("RootView Appeared")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) {
                fruit in FruitView(fruit: fruit).environmentObject(fruitController)
            }
        }
    }

struct FruitView: View {
    // the state that will change and not be initialised
    @State private var showMoreText = false
    @State private var counter = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var fruitViewController: FruitViewController
    var fruit: Fruit
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("Selected fruit: " + fruit.id)
        Text("How many updates: \(counter)")
        if (showMoreText) {
            Text("The text should disappear when moving to another fruit")
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Who is in the fruitList")
                ForEach(fruitViewController.fruitList) {
                    aFruit in Button(aFruit.id) {
                        counter += 1
                        fruitViewController.openView(fruit: aFruit)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HStack(spacing:10) {
                Text("Who is in the visibility stack")
                ForEach(fruitViewController.visibilityStack) {
                    aFruit in Button(aFruit.id) {
                        counter += 1
                        fruitViewController.openView(fruit: aFruit)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        } else {
            Button("Show other fruits", action: showButtons)
        }
        }.onDisappear() {
            print("Fruit view \(fruit.id) is gone")
        }.onAppear() {
            print("Hi I'm \(fruit.id), I'm new here.")
            //dump(env)
        }
    }
    
    // let's change the state
    func showButtons() {
        showMoreText = true
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be the behavior Adkarma wants. They don't want to go deeper and deeper. They want a hard swap at the identical position? Correct? The `NavigationStack` seems to try to increase efficiency by not destroying an existing view of the same type, which of course leaves the @State objects intact.

The navigation path is being driven by a binding to an `Array` inside an `ObservableObject`. The `NavigationStack` continues to believe that it is at `fruitViewController.visibilityStack[0]` ... because it is. It doesn't seem to care about the content inside the wrapper beyond its Type.

The preserved FruitView will re-run the body code, but since it isn't a "new view" (It's still good old NavigationStack[0] as FruitView)it will not hard refresh the @State vars.

But "I zero'd that out!" you say, but `NavigationStack` seems to have copy of it that DIDN'T, and it won't until it can make a new view appear, which it doesn't need to because there is in fact still something at NavigationStack[0] right away again.

I think Adkarma is spot on that this is related to deep linking and here are some articles I quite liked about that:

- https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/78-reverse-engineering-swiftui-s-navigationpath-codability
- https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/21/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-deep-linking/

Also interesting:

- https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/

For what it's worth, to "get it done" I would just reset the variables in View when there is a content change in the Nav array explicitly checking with an `onReceive`, but I agree that seems a bit messy. I also would be interested if anyone has a more elegant solution to a hard swap of a navigation path that ends up at the same type of view at the same "distance" from the root like Adkarma's example.

```
struct FruitView: View {
    // the state that will change and not be initialised
    @State private var showMoreText = false
    @State private var counter = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var fruitViewController: FruitViewController
    var fruit: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selected fruit: " + fruit.id)
            Text("How many updates: \(counter)")
            if (showMoreText) {
                Text("The text should disappear when moving to another fruit")
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text("Who is in the fruitList")
                    ForEach(fruitViewController.fruitList) {
                        aFruit in Button(aFruit.id) {
                            counter += 1
                            fruitViewController.openView(fruit: aFruit)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Button("Show other fruits", action: showButtons)
            }
        }.onReceive(fruitViewController.$visibilityStack) { value in
            counter = 0
            showMoreText = false
            
        }
        
    }

    // let's change the state
    func showButtons() {
        showMoreText = true
    }
}
```

FWIW a `NavigationPath` will also be looking at position/type pair rather than complete content so you will still need to look at it with `.onRecieve` or use an `.id(some Hashable)` on the view calls.

Edited to add:
A strange thing the following function "works" (it send the user to the root view for a split second and then navigates back out), up until the time is decreased under the amount of time it takes the rootView to load.

```
    func jumpView(fruit: Fruit) {
        visibilityStack.removeAll()
        Task { @MainActor in
            //The time delay may be device/app specific. 
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 500_000_000)
            visibilityStack.append(fruit)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your view and solution. You are right about the hard swipe. You can think of a photo gallery. You click on a photo, it appears within a carousel. You can then swipe left and right, it will replace the photo. And click on the back button will bring you back to the gallery.
With the deprecated _NavigationView_ and _isPresented_, this was super easy. The system was smoothly managing the view creation/destruction each time the _isPresented_ state was changed.
Now it will require a lot of additional code and logic. As you say, this seems very messy. I honestly consider this as a bug.

Comment: I think I've started to understand some of the efficiency/something must always be on screen reasons for it, but yeah, it took me by surprise that this was the behavior too. Thank you for posting. Interesting problem.

Comment: I didn't know the _.id(id: Hashable)_. After testing, it brings a clean answer to my immediate need. Many thanks. When transitioning my code, the swiftwithmajid link was my reference ;-)

Comment: I learned something too! ;-) Great question.