# Why are objects still in memory after emptying NavigationStack path?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, memory-leaks, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to implement a Coordinator for managing a flow. The state is stored inside the CoordinatorStore. There are 2 @Published properties for managing the flow. The ***screen*** property controls which View is currently shown and ***path*** controls the navigation stack of the stack view. Details of the implementation can be found below.

With the current implementation and after the following actions: **showA** -> **showB** -> **showInitial** -> **Go to Stack**

I would expect that StoreA and StoreB would be deallocated from memory since ***path***, which holds StoreA and StoreB via enum associated values, gets emptied.

But that doesn't happen, and if I repeat the actions again there would be 2 StoreA and 2 StoreB in memory and so on. Am I missing something?

I will also attach a screenshot of the memory debugger snapshot after doing the initial set of actions.

```swift
enum Path: Hashable {
    case a(StoreA)
    case b(StoreB)
}

enum Screen {
    case initial
    case stack
}

final class CoordinatorStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [Path] = []
    @Published var screen: Screen = .stack
    
    func showA() {
        let store = StoreA()
        path.append(.a(store))
    }
    
    func showB() {
        let store = StoreB()
        path.append(.b(store))
    }
    
    func showInitial() {
        path = []
        screen = .initial
    }
    
    func showStack() {
        screen = .stack
    }
}
```

```swift
struct Coordinator: View {
    @ObservedObject var store: CoordinatorStore
    
    var body: some View {
        switch store.screen {
        case .initial: initial
        case .stack: stack
        }
    }
    
    var stack: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $store.path) {
            VStack {
                Text("Root")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: self.store.showA) {
                    Text("Push A")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Path.self) { path in
                switch path {
                case .a(let store):
                    ViewA(store: store)
                        .toolbar {
                            Button(action: self.store.showB) {
                                Text("Push B")
                            }
                        }
                case .b(let store):
                    ViewB(store: store)
                        .toolbar {
                            Button(action: self.store.showInitial) {
                                Text("Show Initial")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var initial: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Initial")
            Button(action: store.showStack) {
                Text("Go to Stack")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ViewA: View {
    @ObservedObject var store: StoreA
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("View A")
    }
}

final class StoreA: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    deinit {
        print("Deinit: \(String(describing: self))")
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ViewB: View {
    @ObservedObject var store: StoreB
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("View B")
    }
}

final class StoreB: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    deinit {
        print("Deinit: \(String(describing: self))")
    }
}
```

[image: Memory Debugger Snapshot deb]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is related but not identical to:

- [Found a strange behaviour of @State when combined to the new Navigation Stack - Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885353/found-a-strange-behaviour-of-state-when-combined-to-the-new-navigation-stack/)

The `Navigation` api seems to be prioritizing efficiency (inits are expensive) and that SOMETHING must always be on screen. It doesn't seem to de-initialize views that have been disappeared until it has a replacement initialized and appeared.

That can lead to a memory leak ([I believe](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716804)) if you try to manage `Navigation` framework views with something outside of the Navigation framework, but it appears as long as the `Navigation` framework stays in charge things will be de-inted eventually, but not until the new view is init-ed.

### NEWER VERSION

This version uses one coordinator, but preserves the separate enums and views for the initial vs main app pathways.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum AppSceneTvTe:Hashable {
    case setup
    case app
}

enum PathTvTeOptions: Hashable {
    case optionA(OptionAVM)
    case optionB(OptionBVM)
}
```

```
struct SplashTVTEView: View {
    @StateObject var oneCoordinator = CoordinatorTvTe()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $oneCoordinator.path) {
            splash
                .navigationDestination(for: AppSceneTvTe.self) { scene in
                switch scene {
                case .app:
                    SplashTvTeAppRootView().environmentObject(oneCoordinator)
                    
                default:
                    splash
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    var splash: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Splash Page")
            Button(action:navigateToApp) {
                Text("Go App Root")
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
    
    func navigateToApp() {
        oneCoordinator.showStack()
    }
}
```

```
final class CoordinatorTvTe: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()

    
    func showA() {
        path.append(PathTvTeOptions.optionA(OptionAVM()))
    }
    
    func showB() {
        path.append(PathTvTeOptions.optionB(OptionBVM()))
    }
    
    func showInitial() {
        unwindAll()
        //path = NavigationPath()
    }
    
    func showStack() {
        path = NavigationPath()
        path.append(AppSceneTvTe.app)
    }
    
    func unwindAll() {
        while !path.isEmpty {
            path.removeLast()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SplashTvTeAppRootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: CoordinatorTvTe

    
    var body: some View {
      
            VStack {
                Text("Real Root")
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: self.navigation.showA) {
                    Text("Push A")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: PathTvTeOptions.self) { path in
                switch path {
                case .optionA(let vm):
                    OptionAView(vm: vm)
                        .toolbar {
                            Button(action: self.navigation.showB) {
                                Text("Push B")
                            }
                        }
                case .optionB(let vm):
                    OptionBView(vm: vm)
                        .toolbar {
                            Button(action: self.navigation.showInitial) {
                                Text("Show Initial")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }

    }
    
}
```

### OLDER VERSION

Currently the way out of this is to keep it all in the Navigation Stack so no separate Scene vs. Path.

This code uses a boolean to control the Initial screen, but it could be one of the path options - which is the commented out code.

EDITED TO ADD: Tuns out the boolean solution gets weird when you try to make the initial state true. The Stack keeps winning, so I've taken it out.

```
enum Path: Hashable {
    case initial
    case a(StoreA)
    case b(StoreB)
}
```

```
final class CoordinatorStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [Path] = [.initial]
    
    func showA() {
        let store = StoreA()
        path.append(.a(store))
    }
    
    func showB() {
        let store = StoreB()
        path.append(.b(store))
    }
    
    func showInitial() {
        path = []
        path.append(.inital)

    }
    
    func showStack() { 
        path = []
    }
}
```

```
struct Coordinator: View {
    @ObservedObject var store: CoordinatorStore

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $store.path) {
            VStack {
                Text("Real Root")
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: self.store.showA) {
                    Text("Push A")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Path.self) { path in
                switch path {
                case .a(let store):
                    ViewA(store: store)
                        .toolbar {
                            Button(action: self.store.showB) {
                                Text("Push B")
                            }
                        }
                case .b(let store):
                    ViewB(store: store)
                        .toolbar {
                            Button(action: self.store.showInitial) {
                                Text("Show Initial")
                            }
                        }
                case .initial:
                    initial
                }

            }
        }
    }
    
    var initial: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Initial")
            Button(action: store.showStack) {
                Text("Go to Stack")
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I edited my question, it should have been showA -> showB -> showInitial -> Go to Stack. So to answer your last question, it will not deinit and repeating that would lead to more memory leaks. Repeating the pattern would increase the count in memory by 1 for each store which would be in the path .

Comment: So I still get the ```Deinit: <StoreA: 0x60000140ca70>, Deinit: <StoreB: 0x600001404ee0>```but I did not double check the memory. I'm about to update my answer with a "fix" for your purposes, but not a fix for the memory leak that I agree you've found!

Comment: Yeah, if you keep doing the flow that I described it will eventually deinit and reinit again, effectively having only 1 object in memory per store, but if I would introduce another coordinator which manages this coordinator and 1 more, it would lead to the same problem which you solved in your edit. For more complex flows we can not have everything fit into a single NavigationStack therefore your code is more of a workaround then a long term solution. We should probably file a bug to Apple for this issue.

Comment: Agreed. It's really fragile. I did file a FeedBack, but I did it for an if-statement flow control. It can only help for you to do it for a case-statement! https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716804 Feedback FB11643551

Comment: Referring to your first comment: "That can lead to a memory leak (I believe) if you try to manage Navigation framework views with something outside of the Navigation framework" . After a few days of experimenting I found a weird workaround for it. If you wrap the instance of a Coordinator which manages a NavigationStack inside a TabView or NavigationView where it is used, it will deinit itself as intended after switching from it.

Comment: Yes! As long as things stay managed by a SwiftUI `Navigation` aware structure it seems to keep things managed I think the internal type is called something like `NavigationRegistrar` or something like it.